# Tableview cells not showing up correctly, and core data not loading the saved data correctly

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, tableview

in my app I am trying to create a budgeting app. I have tried creating a custom tableView Cell, but when it is run in the simulator, the tableView is condensed and does not show up correctly. As well as this, I am trying to save and load data from Coredata. However when the viewController loads, the error "Fatal Error: Index Out of Range" appears. I have viewed many coreData tutorials and threads however none of them help with my issue.

I want my tableViews to show up like this: [storyboard view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNZsJ.png)
However they appear [like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBpt6.png)

Here is my code for the tableView and core data.
Any help is appreciated, thank you!
**ViewController**

```
var goals: [NSManagedObject] = []

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(goals.count)
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! AllGoalsTableViewCell
    let goal = goals[1]
    
    cell.titleLabel?.text = goal.value(forKey: "title") as? String
    
    return cell
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    
    
    
    //1
    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
        return
    }
    
    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    
    //2
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Goal")
    
    //3
    do {
        goals = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
    
    if !self.goals.isEmpty
    {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

**addNewViewController**

```
var goals: [NSManagedObject] = []

func save(title: String, goalAmount: Double, percent: Double, amountPerWeek: Double) {
    
    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
        return
    }
    
    //1
    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    
    //2
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Goal", in: managedContext)!
    
    let goal = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: managedContext)
    
    //3
    goal.setValue(title, forKey: "title")
    goal.setValue(goalAmount, forKey: "goalAmount")
    goal.setValue(percent, forKey: "percent")
    goal.setValue(amountPerWeek, forKey: "amountPerWeek")
    
    //4
    do {
        try managedContext.save()
        goals.append(goal)
        
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}

@IBAction func addNewAction(_ sender: Any) 
    //CoreData
    self.save(title: title, goalAmount: goalAmount ?? 0.0, percent: percent,    amountPerWeek: amountPerWeekFloat ?? 0.0)
    print("saved")
}
```

Comment: why would you return `goals.count` from `heightForRowAt`? it should be [numberOfRowsInSection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614931-tableview)

Comment: and read `goals[indexPath.row]` instead of `goals[1]`

Comment: well spotted @PhilipDukhov.  So used to seeing that code in numberOfRows that I didn't even look at the method signature!  Careless of me.

Comment: @flanker My attention was caught by `CGFloat(goals.count)`, I didn't look at the method signature too before that=)

Comment: Oh my, I have spent a good half hour trying to figure it out before coming here, I read it all so many times and it must have just slipped my mind! I am so stupid HAHA. it is like midnight here so that might be why. Thank you for your help !!